# ADFS fails to authenticate specific user -- throws ADAccountLookupException

Tags: adfs

*Note - I've actually already solved this, but I don't see any detailed write-ups online about this issue so I'll go ahead and ask the question and answer it myself.*

I run a service that authenticates as *SMTPRelayUser* that started failing ADFS authentication about 95% of the time.  Inexplicably, this user would very occasionally succeed in authenticating and send all the mail that had queued up over time.  In the ADFS Event Viewer logs, I was seeing two errors -- Event 300 and Event 413.  Event ID 300 offered up no useful information, but 413 notified me of a strange exception.

```
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.AccountPolicy.ADAccountLookupException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.AccountPolicy.ADAccountLookupException' was thrown.
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the replication of this account across domain controllers and could see no reason that this should be failing.  I turned on ADFS Debug logging and tried to login again.  This time I was rewarded with a very clear warning that proceeded the *ADAccountLookupException* in the ADFS Tracing Debug log.

**Event ID 53:** *AccountLockoutPolicy.IsAccountThrottled: The system failed to read the bad password count for user SMTPRelayUser@mydomain.com*.

After checking the *badPwdCount* AD attribute for SMTPRelayUser on the DC being favored by my ADFS farm, I saw that it was indeed *not set*.

At this point I remembered that I had enabled [ADFS 2012 R2 Extranet Lockout Protection](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2014/05/05/enabling-adfs-2012-r2-extranet-lockout-protection.aspx) a while back and it coincided with the onset of the login issues.  Apparently there is a bug in Extranet Lockout Protection feature that throws an exception if *badPwdCount* is unset.  I disabled the Extranet Lockout Protection feature and the login worked perfectly.

So why then did my authentications work 5% of the time?  The *badPwdCount* is not replicated across domain controllers.  Each DC keeps its own count.  Occasionally, ADFS would actually consult a DC that had a *badPwdCount* value set and succeed authentication.

The moral of the story is to be careful if you're using the Extranet Lockout Protection feature in ADFS.  I myself have simply disabled it for the time being.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2971171 was released to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up.  Curiously, I think the listed scenario isn't completely accurate.  A gMSA account is not required for this issue to crop up -- I wasn't using a gMSA.  It also doesn't list the _Extranet Lockout Protection_ feature as a prerequisite.  All the same, I do believe that this might resolve the issue.  I noticed that you work for Microsoft, if you could check on the veracity of the **Symptoms** section it would be much appreciated.

Comment: yes the GMSA stuff is a mistake when article was written. When this was originally reported the email thread and repro conditions were explained as gmsa and new user blah blah. Somehow that seems to have been used when article was written. I am already in the process of getting that fixed. Just will take a little while due to Q&A process etc.